# Build jhipster monolithic application using docker container

Tags: jhipster

I have a jhipster monolithic application which I want to build using a docker container. I'm trying to use a jdk docker image and then install nodejs inside it by passing `-PnodeInstall`. However after sever attempts and trying out different options, I failed to build a docker image of my application. Here is the command which I tried to use:

`docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app anapsix/alpine-java:8u162b12_jdk ./gradlew -PnodeInstall bootRepackage -Pdev buildDocker`

Please suggest if somebody has tried this before and how to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to install node? Why running the app using gradle? if you want it for dev only it's simpler to use jhipster devbox, if it's for prod then you don't need node nor gradle

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I want it for prod. I basically want to build and deploy the application on AWS ECS using Atlassian Bamboo. How do I build without gradle? Can you let me know the command I should be using?

Comment: See our doc: http://www.jhipster.tech/production/ you build in dev using prod profile to generate an executable war file and a docker container.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I followed the documentation. But my problem is my bamboo agent does not have JDK, Node, Yarn installed. So, essentially I have to build the application inside a jdk docker container. For that matter, I tried to use `fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk8-jdk` image and executed `docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk8-jdk ./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage`, but it fails during yarnSetup

Comment: There is already a jhipster image in the docker-hub, with all needed tools like Node included: https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster/

Comment: But isn't that image meant to generate a boilerplate jhipster project? Or it can be used to compile and build the war file as well?

Answer (score 1):

As @Meier said, `jhipster/jhipster` docker image can help **avoid setting up ones own workstation to build a JHipster project**. I used:

```
docker run -v .:/home/jhipster/app \
  -v ~/.m2:/home/jhipster/.m2 --rm jhipster/jhipster \
  ./mvnw clean install
```

> Please note that the user running the build will be `jhipster(uid=1000)` so your files permissions might change to uid 1000.

Answer (score 0):

To build a docker image from your jhipster project run:

```
$ ./mvnw clean verify -Pprod dockerfile:build
$ docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up -d
```

This will build the image and run with docker compose in the background.

If youve made edits and the tests fail, you can put `-DskipTests=true` on your build command

Comment: That is not the requirement. Read the comments in the original post to get an idea of what I'm exactly looking for.

Answer (score -1):

How can we deploy a application by using Docker in Jhipster 
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jb21o6VLrw4&feature=youtu.be

```
$ $ mkdir demo
$ cd demo/
$ jhipster
$ jhipster docker-compose
$ ./mvnw -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild
$ docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up -d
$ docker image ls -a
$ docker-compose up
$ docker-compose down
```